# MS Excel: Writing formula to calculate the average time

Tags: excel, datetime

I have a sheet with in-time and out-time recorded in 24 hour time format. (A1 contains in-time and A2 contains out-time). The in-time and out-time are provided for all dates in a month. So some of the cells contain text, like in case of holidays, the cell contains 'H' and in case of weekends, the cell contains either 'SAT' or 'SUN'. I have figured out to get the total time by using the formula below (with formatting cell as hh:mm):

=ABS(Sheet1!A1-Sheet1!A2)

Now I would like to avoid getting #VALUE! errors for the holidays and weekends and calculate the average total time.

Can someone help? Below is a sample data that shows cells containing total time and text.

```
Dates     1     2     3      4      5     6    ...           AVG
ABC1      H   4.00  12.00   7.45   SAT   SUN   ...        <avg time>
ABC2      H   8.00  13.00   8.45   SAT   SUN   ...        <avg time>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ISNUMBER() function to only consider the times and ignore the letters: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnumber.php